# Quantify product-appropriateness score

Tags: word-choice, sentence

I'm looking for a way to quantify and explain the scenario below to my managers. I'm really good at understanding issues, but unfortunately no so good at communicating them to others. I have written some code that works out scores or should I save appropriateness of a product for a customer.  I now need to explain how this works to my non-technical managers as simply as I can maybe with one sentence.

Can anyone help out and give me a sentence to explain the following example:

```
**PRODUCT** 
Ball 

Must have Bat
Must be age 8-99
```

---

```
**PERSON**
Jake
age 30

Score = 50%
```

the system looks at the total possible score for product. In the case of Bat this is 2 (because we have two possible requirements for bat). Person has just one matching item. So the product appropriateness would come out as 50%.

Here is another example:

```
**PRODUCT** 
House 

Must be a person
Must be age 18-65
Must be employed
Must have Money
```

---

```
**PERSON**
John

is a person * edit
age 16
has Money
is employed

Score = 75%
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for not answering with an actual answer but I still don't have the reputation needed to leave comments... I just wanted to point out that maybe your second exampled is wrong, if I have understood what are you doing here, shouldn't John have a 75% score being a person, having money and being employed? It makes 3 requirements satisfied out of 4!

Comment: I edited to try to clarify. Please review changes to ensure this is what you intended.

Comment: I don't think questions asking for sentences to be written are on topic.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Writing advice is off topic per the [FAQ]. Might be on topic at Writers.SE but please check their FAQ first. Thanks.

Comment: @MετάEd - Thanks for the mention, but I'm afraid that requests to rephrase small bits of text are [off-topic on Writers](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/535/26). If this user had a longer piece of copy (say a few paragraphs) it would be on-topic, but the intent of this question might be lost. This sounds  like something that could be most easily addressed in chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

> This sytem assigns a number of criteria to a product, checks how many of those criteria the potential customer meets and assigns a percentage score based on that comparison.